# Programatically generate stack trace in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, stack-trace

I am interested in getting a readable stack-trace when my iPhone/iPad crashes.  I would like to send this information to our server once it is trapped.  I know there are tools like Crashlytics that do this very well, but we would like to stay away from any 3rd party tools if at all possible.  The only way I know to get this info is to manually do it by retrieving the and then have that file symbolicated on a Mac before it can be analyzed. Even doing this can be troublesome if you don't have a copy of the original application binary and the .dSYM file that was generated when that binary was built. I believe Crashlytics does this somehow without the actual binary or the .dSYM file which leads me to believe that a simple stack trace can be generate programmatically.  Has anyone done this or have any pointers as to how I could do this within Objective C so that I could send that information to our servers for Error reporting?

Is it at all possible to get a create a readable stack-trace within Objective C on my iOS device without having to first send that file to a Mac with both the actual binary or the .dSYM file?

Comment: Look into PLCrashReporter. It only helps you generate the crash report data or generate a current stack trace if needed. Don't try to write any of that yourself. With that you can write your own code as needed to send the crash report.

Comment: I had a problem getting PLCrashReporter to do what I wanted.  PLCrashReporter generated a PLCrashReport, but I believe the info in there still needs to be symbolicated before it can be read (I believe, correct me if I'm wrong, I didn't spend much time with the tool).  To do that I would first need to have that object symbolicated with a Mac.  I want to see if that can be done directly within the app so this can be sent to a server in a readable format.

Comment: You can't get a symbolicated crash report without processing it along with the dSYM.

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
[NSThread callStackSymbols]
```

Comment: ... and, I guess, modify your main.m to catch exceptions in the first place? The author might need to look into `signal` for the C-level exceptions.

Comment: This answer barely covers a single point in the question. This answer needs a lot more info to actually answer the question.